# OO PHP Functions

Tags: php, oop, class

I am fairly new to PHP OOP, the problem that I am have is that I can't wrap my head around the follow layout of my script:

- main class is set which sets up the page and extends a mysql class and creates the database connect through the __construct
- within main class i run a public function which includes() a file and accesses a function that is in that include file
- within the function that is in the included file i can't seem to access the main class through neither the actual global variable or use $this->blah

does anyone have any pointers or direction. i tried googling it but couldn't come across anything remotely close to what i was trying to do.

it is started with: - works

```
$gw = new GWCMS();
```

then inside of the _construct of GWCMS() which GWCMS extends mySQL - works

```
parent::__construct(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
$this->build();
```

then it calls build() - works

```
public function build(){
   ...
   $page['content'] = $this->plugins($page['content']);
   ...
   $output = $this->output($theme,$page);
   echo eval('?>' . $output);
}
```

which calls plugins() - we start having problems

```
public function plugins($content){
   $x = 0;
   if ($handle = opendir(STOCKPLUGINPATH)) {
      while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
         if(is_dir(STOCKPLUGINPATH . $entry . '/') && $entry != '.' && $entry != '..'){ 
            if(file_exists(STOCKPLUGINPATH . $entry . '/inc.php')){
               include(STOCKPLUGINPATH . $entry . '/inc.php');
               $content = do_shortcode($content);
            }
         }
      }
      closedir($handle);
   }
   return $content;
}
```

the previous code includes inc.php which lists the files to be include:

```
include(STOCKPLUGINPATH . 'Test/test.php');
```

test.php includes the list of functions. the do_shortcode above accesses the functions without a problem and does the work however i need the following function which is in the test.php to access the $gw->fetchAssoc(); which fetchAssoc is in the parent of gwcms

```
function justtesting2($attr){
   $config = $gw->fetchAssoc("Select * from gw_config");
   foreach($config as $c){
      echo $c['value'];
   }
}
```

when i run the script i get

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAssoc() on a non-object in /home/globalwe/public_html/inhouse/GWCMS/gw-includes/plugins/Test/test.php on line 9
```

Comment: We need to see code. Post the relevant parts only, please.

Comment: `$this` is not in scope in that function, why your 'global' does not work... probably because it's not in global scope either, but in another scope. Hard to tell without a (minimalistic!) code example.

Comment: Global doesn't sound really OOP'ish at all.

Comment: main class should not extend the mysql class, what you should be doing is having a bootstrapper that loads the required classes and dependency injects or load your classes into a registry class and pass that to the constructors.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone don't you think you're pushing him into the deep end? Off a cliff... into the deep end? Not learning OOP principles and learning dependency injection creates that kind of android-programmers from hell that were *born* into a design pattern and still don't understand either it or OOP and create the most gut-wrenching spaghetti and meat balls (that's spaghetty code + oop objects).

Comment: @Nate it's true that your aplication doesn't **revolve** around your SQL class... like all other classes, the SQL class is a tool. you don't have to make it the center of your application.

Comment: sorry about not having code snippets i have added those in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing OOP code means restructuring to avoid that mess of files and functions dropped into what ever files and god knows what not.

Try to rely on writing a class that models the behavior you want to achieve. The class should contain property values that carry data for you and methods that help the class *behave* like the thing you're modeling it to.

To answer your question:

```
class MyClass {
    public $my_property = 4;
    public function MyMethod() {
        include('file.php');
    }
    public function MyOtherMethod() {
        $this; // is accessible because MyOtherMethod
               // is a method of class MyClass
    }
}

// contents of file.php

$variable = 3;

function MyFunction($parameter) {
    global $variable; // is accessible
    $parameter; // is accessible
    $this // is not accessible because it was
          // not passed to MyFunction as a parameter
          // nor was it declared as a global variable

    // MyFunction is not a method of class MyClass,
    // there is no reason why $this would be accessible to MyFunction
    // they are not "related" in any OOP way
    // this is called variable scoping and/or object scoping
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When files are included into functions, they only have access from that function's scope:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-136

You need to give the reference to the object you've created to the function that includes the file, or pull it into that function's scope to access it.